# FileNotfoundException when trying to checkin Foursquare using Android

Tags: android, foursquare

I tried looking for answers for this since last few days with no luck, Even some of the stackoverflow answers did not help.

I am trying to checkin a user after receiving his UserToken via Android. I get a `FileNotfoundException` at `getInputStream()`, non authenticated APIs like 
`"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories"` work well. Am i missing something?

```
    URL url = new URL("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?oauth_token="+token);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.addRequestProperty("venueId","12238");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    String response = streamToString(is);
    return response;
```

Managed to solve this after lot of effort. See my answer below.

Comment: probably a 404 response from the server. Check the response code

Comment: It works well with the browser, when i put the URL.

Comment: the browser? Are you sure you have to perform a POST op instead of a GET?

Comment: i used a browser plugin to POST venueid value.

Comment: Probably the issue is linked to the authentication. Have you tried c.setRequestProperty("Authorization","basic " + 
Base64.encode("myuser:mypass".getBytes()));

Comment: no authorization is required for Foursquare with user/pass as we are not supposed to store the username and password of user, instead we use the token

Comment: So Does  "conn.addRequestProperty("venueid","12238");" is useless ?

Comment: It adds a POST property(i am assuming) as i need venueid to checking.

Comment: Never mind. Check the server response code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie I finally managed to solve the problem, I don't know what exactly was the problem with my code above but the following worked.

This API requires a POST call but even the venueID must be part of the URL and addRequestProperty does not seem to be sending the venueID properly. Hence I changed the code to

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?venueId=12238&oauth_token="+token);
```

And this solved the problem. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the oauth_token using the same method you use to add the venueid. Also, your venueid is invalid, so make sure you are checking the user in to a real venue.

Comment: Tried this, not working, plus the venueId is right as i tested it via a browser plugin giving both the values via POST

Comment: The venueid parameter you wrote in your example cannot be right. Venue ID parameters are 24 character long hex strings. You should try composing the URL manually and using CURL to verify that it works. This will let you inspect the response for errors.

Comment: I tried this venue ID via a browser and works perfectly fine, I will try again via CURL

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpURLConnection` class is misleading in that it will throw a `FileNotFoundException` for any HTTP error code of 400 or above.

So it's not necessarily an incorrect URL (404) it could be 400 (bad request), 403 (forbidden), 500 (internal server error) etc.

Use the [`getResponseCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) method to get a more precise indication of the problem.

Comment: You are right about this, it was misleading, I had to use the browser to get the right error code. Next time will keep this in mind. But what do u think is the reason why when I pass the parameters in the URL it works and not via AddRequestProperty?

Answer (score 0):

**first**: Yoy have https url, and trying to create HttpURLConnection. You should use HttpsURLConnection.

**Second**: You can try to add conn.setDoOutput(true), "post" request requires  it. And without it server can try give a get request from you despite on conn.setRequestMethod("POST"). Also you can check headers from your browser plugin, and put them into your request.